# 'no python application found' in Django

Tags: django, uwsgi

I tried to deploy my Django project on server with uwsgi.

I can initial uwsgi with `uwsgi --ini conf/uwsgi.ini`

But when I tried to visit the website, I got this error

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 11228|app: -1|req: -1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {46 vars in 946 bytes} [Mon Nov 28 17:06:37 2022] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

I put my repo at https://github.com/dolphinfafa/MyLife

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Comment: Check your `wsgi.py` location

Comment: thx, I already solved it

Comment: If you've solved it then put it as an answer it may help other readers